# Interactively change the selectInput choices

Tags: r, search, user-interaction, shiny

Originally I create this shiny interface that takes in a parameter "company id" and "date", but here we have a problem: most people dont know the companies we work with by their id, only their name, i.e. (McDonalds, Radioshack).

So I want to ideally create a search function like this 
[image]

My current idea is to pass in a table including a list of all our partner companies and their ids to global.R.   Then pass in the textInput as the search variables and perform the search on server side. However, I get lost on how to pass searchResults back into the UI on a selectInput panel?

My current code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(


  sidebarPanel(

    textInput("nameSearch", "Or, Search for company name", 'McDonald'),
    selectInput("partnerName", "Select your choice", list( "searchResults" ),
    br(),
    submitButton("Update View"),
    br(),

  ),
```

server.R

```
  shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #subTable
  searchResult<- reactive({
    subset(partners, grepl(input$nameSearch, partners$name))
  })

  output$searchResults <- renderTable({ 
    searchResult[,1]
    })
```

global.R

```
partners<- read.csv("partnersList.csv", fill=TRUE)
```

partnersList is just in this format

```
    name            id 
 ------------------
    McDonalds        1
    Wendy's          2
    Bestbuy          3
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to make the UI reactive. I haven't tested this (miss data for it too) but should work I think. In `server.R` add:

```
output$selectUI <- renderUI({ 
selectInput("partnerName", "Select your choice", searchResult()[,1] ),
})
```

And in `ui.R` replace the selectInput with:

```
htmlOutput("selectUI")
```

Comment: I've had success with this.  Here's an alternative that I have not tried: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/shiny-discuss/JGJx5A3Ge-A

Comment: thanks Sacha this worked for me.   GSee: that new development is going be amazing!!

Comment: This doesn't work in R Markdown. Any ideas on how to do this in R Markdown?

Comment: so my problem with this is that it's invisible in the beginning. how can i make the entire list visible from the very beginning then weed out the results using the search bar?

Comment: Note that the values can be accessed normally via input$partnerName

Answer (score 7):

In Shiny version 0.8 (where I have tested it), in `server.R` add the following:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    # This will change the value of input$partnerName to searchResult()[,1]
    updateTextInput(session, "partnerName", 
                    label = "Select your choice", 
                    value = searchResult()[,1])
  })

})
```

Now the function within `shinyServer` has additional argument `session`.

You can skip the label if you don't need to change it.

You don't need to change anything in `ui.R`.

Comment: This is the best solution for the latest versions of shiny

Answer (score 3):

Reply from Rstudio's JC:

> Sure, just use a textInput for the search string, and use
>   renderUI/uiOutput  to make a dynamic selectInput. Then the rest of
>   your code can depend on the selectInput's value. (Make sure to check
>   for NULL or whatever when reading the selectInput value, because it
>   will start out with no value.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correcly, all you need to do is display to the user **company names** and have **company ids** passed to the server.

I suppose this feature was not available back in the days (and you had to work around as suggested above) but nowadays the argument choices in selectInput function accepts named lists exactly for this need. Hopefully example below clarifies the situation.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

companies <- tribble(
    ~name, ~id,
    "McDonalds", 1,
    "Wendy's", 2,
    "Bestbuy", 3
)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("select_company_ui"),
    textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$select_company_ui <- renderUI({
        selectInput("select_company", "Select company", choices = deframe(companies))
    })
    
    output$value <- renderText(paste0("Value of the company filter is ", input$select_company))
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here you can see the resulting app:

[image]

Side note: I use function deframe from package tibble to turn a tibble into a named list just for convenience, you could do without it by writing

```
choices = c("McDonalds" = 1, "Wendy's" = 2, "Bestbuy" = 3)
```