# R Shiny Server: Interactively change the selectInput choices?

Tags: r, shiny

my question is nearly identical to this [Interactively change the selectInput choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173325/r-shiny-interactively-change-the-selectinput-choices?rq=1), except that I am trying to do this on Shiny Server.  Sacha's answer worked perfectly for me in regular Shiny, but when I run over Shiny Server, the `htmlOutput("selectUI")` from `ui.R` becomes:

```
<div id="selectUI" class="shiny-html-output"></div>
```

in the source code, and does not render at all.

I have zero experience with HTML or JavaScript, so the other support I've been reading, most notable the link from GSee in question I linked to, is way over my head.

Is there a way of interactively changing the `selectInput()` choices through Shiny Server, and if so, does someone have an example that an HTML newbie could actually follow?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you positive the file "partnersList.csv" is available in the same folder as your R files? Shiny-server uses the same shiny package so there should be no difference. You could try to set the full path to the data file just to make sure.

Comment: No, that isn't be the problem.  I believe the problem is in that Shiny Server uses index.html instead of ui.R.  Therefore, some Javascript needs to be inserted into index.html.  I'm not sure if I just need to learn Javascript for this functionality or if there is a way to do this with R code