# .html plotGoogleMap does not load in shiny App when deployed on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, plotgooglemaps

I am trying to embed a `plotGoogleMap` in a shiny app online. 
Locally the app works perfectly, but when uploading via `shinyapps` to shinyapps.io the .html map does not load.

*Any ideas how to solve this issue?*

---

See my code below.

**ui.R**

```
library('markdown')
library('shiny')

shinyUI(navbarPage("plotGooleMaps in shinyapps",
                   mainPanel(uiOutput('mymap'))
                  )
       )
```

**server.R**

```
library('shiny')
library('plotGoogleMaps')

shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$mymap <- renderUI({
    data(meuse)
    coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
    proj4string(meuse) <- CRS("+init=epsg:28992")
    m <- plotGoogleMaps(meuse, filename = 'myMap1.html', openMap = F)
    tags$iframe(
      srcdoc = paste(readLines('myMap1.html'), collapse = '\n'),
      width = "900Px",
      height = "500Px"
      )
  })
})
```

**deploy app with** `shinyapps`

```
library('shinyapps')
setwd("~/working directory where ui.R and server.R are located locally")
deployApp()
```

---

This is the error log but I dont know what to conclude from it:

```
[blocked] The page at 'about:srcdoc' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran 
insecure content from 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false': 
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS. about:srcdoc:1

     Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined about:srcdoc:21

GET https://chamaoskurumi.shinyapps.io/TESTmapSHINY
           /_w_cf38cbc66a336eaf0ab8b4e184402cba949ec9bc0b5cc5c0/Legendf4d2427a4.png 
           404 (Not Found) about:srcdoc:3419

    Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined about:srcdoc:1989
    initializeabout:srcdoc:1989
    onloadabout:srcdoc:3411
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on the shinyapps Forum solved my issue. `http` needs to be replaced by `https` in the map file.
Codewise, this means that:

```
readLines('myMap1.html')
```

needs to be replaced by

```
gsub("http://maps.google.com/", 
     "https://maps.google.com/", 
     readLines('myMap1.html'), 
     fixed=TRUE)
```

I also contacted the author to fix this in the next update of the `plotGoogleMaps` package.
Note that the legend does not function, but that seems to be [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066461/png-legend-of-plotgooglemaps-not-displayed-in-r-shiny-app)