# change selectizeInput choices - wrong values in menu

Tags: r, shiny

I try to make a selection menu like this:

[Interactively change the selectInput choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173325/interactively-change-the-selectinput-choices)

And everything works well with the exception of one thing:
Instead to get the values (like McDonald), I get the indices although I did nothing different (see picture link below). Where could be my mistake?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isSdM.png)

Here my global.R:

```
partners<- read.csv("genes.csv", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#subTable
searchResult<- reactive({
subset(partners, grepl(input$nameSearch, partners$name))
})

output$searchResults <- renderTable({ 
searchResult()[,1]
})


output$selectUI <- renderUI({ 
selectizeInput("partnerName", "Click in and select", choices=searchResult()[,1], multiple=TRUE )
})
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
# Give the page a title
titlePanel("Tilte"),

sidebarPanel(

textInput("nameSearch", "Search for name", "Blah"),
htmlOutput("selectUI"),
br(),
submitButton("Update View"),
br()

),
# Create a spot for the barplot
mainPanel(
textOutput("text"),
plotOutput("plot")  
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not getting indices, but rather the integer representation of a factor.  Check the class of `partners[,1]`.  Try

```
output$selectUI <- renderUI({ 
    selectizeInput("partnerName", "Click in and select",
                   choices=as.character(searchResult()[,1]), multiple=TRUE )
})
```

You could possibly add the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` option when you read the data as well.

Comment: Many thanks, that was the problem and solved the problem! I'm new in R and not so familiar with this factor-"problem". I'm really glad that you gave me the tip!

Comment: No problem, factors are confusing at first, they are stored as integers to save space, and each integer has a label.